# Importing transformers, evaluate, or torch python library and Internal Server Error 500

Tags: python, html, apache, cgi

It seems that when I call a python function from an xmlhttp request so that its output prints to the browser, the script will lead to an error if any of these import statements (commented) are run:

```
import traceback
import transformers

"""
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer

import evaluate
import torch
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datasets
from datasets import load_dataset, load_metric, load_from_disk, Value

import cgi, cgitb

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Hello!")
```

That is, if I keep them commented, my hello statement will show on the browser, otherwise, I get an internal server error 500. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

I already tried suppressing warnings and logs!

Comment: Also, are you getting any errors from wherever you have CGI script errors go?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I get errors if my "content-type" print is *after* the uncommented imports (i.e., internal server error 500), and actually premature status of 200 but no execution to the end of the python script if my "content-type" print is *before* the uncommented imports.